# Is the PHP mail() function supported on GoDaddy Deluxe Hosting 2016 without the use of external libraries?

Tags: php, email, smtp

Questions asked with answers that are already in existence are out of date <= 2014. With PHP being installed on the server it should be obvious that it works but still nothing comes through. I had a chat with GoDaddy and they assured me mail() will work.

I have looked through http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php and there is an example that I have copied with the simple header... but still nothing.

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    $senderName = $_POST["name"];
    $sendTo = $_POST["email"];
    $phoneNumber = $_POST["phone"];
    $message = wordwrap($_POST["message"], 70, "\r\n");
    $headers = "From: gavin667@ulstermaid.lickthescreen.co" . "\r\n" .
                "Reply-To: gavin@lickthescreen.co" . "\r\n" .
                "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $senderName = $_POST["name"];
    $sendTo = $_POST["email"];
    $phoneNumber = $_POST["phone"];
    $message = wordwrap($_POST["message"], 70, "\r\n");
    $headers = "From: gavin667@ulstermaid.lickthescreen.co" . "\r\n" .
                "Reply-To: gavin@lickthescreen.co" . "\r\n" .
                "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

    if(mail($sendTo, "Enquiry", $message, $headers)) {
        echo "Mail Sent Successfully";
    }
    else {
        echo "Sending of email failed";
    }

    error_reporting(-1);
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    set_error_handler("var_dump");
}
```

The if statement returned true but no mail... days later. Any suggestions or any flaws in my PHP?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: there's nothing coming through to the spam either

Comment: did you add the godaddy ip address to the MX record?

Answer (score 0):

Having diagnosed a mail issue with a smtp server before, there are a few checks you need to do.

A server with no additional libraries, other than apache/httpd should be able to send mail via php's mail function.

What is likely happening is that the mail is being blocked on the receiving end.

If you have the ip address of the server you're trying to send the mail to, you will want to do a telnet test to see if your server can connect to the receiving server.

If you can telnet to the receiving server, you will want to check reverse lookup records for your server and if any network firewalls are blocking the mail on the receiving server due to a bad lookup or other setting.

Comment: I'm submitting the data to emails that are held on the same server/shared hosting package. It wouldn't have anything to do with the sub domain?